# Location request first or access to permissions to access location?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, android-location

What is the correct order to ask the user, for location request:

> To continue, turn on device location, which uses Google's location service

Or for permissions to access location (`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`) in order to display the current position of user's device on a map? Thanks!

Comment: ideally both are compulsory. without turning on you will not able to get the location. and with out permission you will not able to send location request. so first ask user to turn on google's location service. on success of that you can ask for permissions.

Comment: @AndroidTeam Is there a down-side if I ask for permissions first and then to turn on google's location service? Thanks!

Comment: No, there is not any down-side if you want to ask permission first then just make sure when you request for location it will ask for turn on google's location service.